# Exporting dataframe via write.csv returns error

Tags: r, export-to-csv

Exporting a dataframe via write.csv, I receive odd errors.

I've tried abbreviating the name of the output file, shuffling the order of the options, swapping " for ' on the file name and back again.

My statement:

```
write.csv <- (CensusAll, row.names=FALSE, file="c:/CensusAll_Apr19.csv")
```

Console shows:

> write.csv <- (CensusAll, row.names=FALSE, file="c:/CensusAll_Apr19.csv")
>   Error: unexpected ',' in "write.csv <- (CensusAll,"

Comment: remove the `<-`. I.e just use `write.csv(CensusAll, row.names=FALSE, file="c:/CensusAll_Apr19.csv")`. voting to close as typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
write.csv <- (CensusAll, row.names=FALSE, file="c:/CensusAll_Apr19.csv")
```

to this:

```
write.csv(CensusAll, row.names=FALSE, file="c:/CensusAll_Apr19.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks...just figured this out, too.